# Optimizing INSERT and Data Retrieval Performance in DuckDB with Large Datasets

Tags: python, sql, performance, query-optimization, duckdb

I am working on a project involving large datasets, and I am utilizing DuckDB to manage my data. I am encountering performance issues when executing INSERT operations compared to SELECT operations, and I am also interested in understanding the most performant way to retrieve data from my SELECT statements.

I am using a Jupyter Notebook environment with Python 3.10.13, DuckDB version '0.9.0' on MacOS.

Below is a sample to reproduce my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import duckdb


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))


%%timeit
duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE A > 50 AND B > 50 AND C > 50 AND D > 50")
> 244 µs ± 25.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%%timeit
duckdb.sql("""
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
        CREATE TABLE test AS
        SELECT * FROM df WHERE A > 50 AND B > 50 AND C > 50 AND D > 50
""")
> 4.95 ms ± 283 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I have also attempted to create the table beforehand to see if it would make a difference:

```
duckdb.sql("CREATE TABLE test (A INTEGER, B INTEGER, C INTEGER, D INTEGER)")

%%timeit
duckdb.sql("""
        INSERT INTO test 
        SELECT * FROM df WHERE A > 50 AND B > 50 AND C > 50 AND D > 50
""")
> 5.62 ms ± 546 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Convert the select in a pandas dataframe seems performing better:

```
%%timeit
duckdb.sql("""
        SELECT * FROM df WHERE A > 50 AND B > 50 AND C > 50 AND D > 50
"""  ).df()
> 3.51 ms ± 363 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Questions:

1. Are there optimizations in DuckDB that I can leverage to expedite the INSERT operation?
2. For data retrieval, is there a more efficient method to retrieve the data from my SELECT statement as opposed to the way I am doing it currently?

I am aiming for faster data handling, and any insights or suggestions on how to optimize the INSERT operation and data retrieval would be highly appreciated.

Comment: make  a primary key and add a combined index on a,b,c,d, if it is not the primary key

Comment: We don't know your data, but if A to D are any old 32 bit integers say, then for the example you've shown, you could add a column maxabsAtoD, index it, and add the line maxabsAtoD < 50. Otherwise I think you're stuck with scanning the whole table.

Comment: Your SELECTs scan a million rows and choose roughly an eighth of them. So your INSERT processes ~125K rows in pretty good time. Without the INSERT you don't do much of anything with the data. SQL, being [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) rather than procedural, detects that and doesn't do much of anything.